# How to print the numbers separately (comma-seperated) using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print the following numbers in line-by-line in **sorted order** using Python.

119, 671, 207, 2484, 6, 941, 2138, 806, 1851, 2509, 1264, 701, 2802, 319, 1603, 98, 347, 525, 1521, 269, 1681, 1885, 1731, 2828, 2543, 2011, 720, 2359, 2248, 22, 1637

My code looks likes

```
>>> fo = open("cr.txt", "r")
>>> fo1 = fo.readlines()
>>> fo2 = fo1.split(',')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

When I was trying to split the numbers using `split`, it shows the **error** as `list object has no attribute split`.

Comment: `split` is a function found on strings. Not lists.

Comment: `readlines()` returns list of strings, each one of them is a line, try to print it to stdout!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fo.readlines()` returns a list of lines.  If your text file only contains one line, then you can use this, which selects the first line in the file.

```
fo = open("cr.txt", "r")
fo1 = fo.readlines()[0]
fo2 = fo1.split(',')
```

If your file contain more than one line then use this, which joins all lines together with ',' before splitting all values by comma.

```
fo = open("cr.txt", "r")
fo1 = ','.join(fo.readlines())
fo2 = fo1.split(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

As the question is to print the numbers in comma-separated line-by-line and in **sorted** fashion, the following code is one solution:

```
f = open("cr.txt", "r")
l = f.read().split(sep = ",")
list1 = sorted(l, key=lambda e: int(e))
for i in list1:
    print(i)
```

And the output is:

```
6
22
98
119
207 
269 
319 
347 
525 
671 
701 
720 
......
```

The code prints the numbers line-by-line in sorted manner and without commas. I have used the `lambda` expression here for the sorting purpose, which can also otherwise achieved by the `sort()` function.